# pandas dataframe contains list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have currently run the following script which uses Fuzzylogic to replace some common words from the list. Dataframe `df1` contains my default list of possible values. Dataframe `df2` is the main dataframe where transformations/changes are undertaken after referring to Dataframe `df1`. The code is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['one','two','three','four','five','tsst'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'not_shifted':[np.nan,'one','too','three','fours','five','six',np.nan,'test']})
# Drop nan value
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2['not_shifted'].fillna(value=''))
df2['not_shifted'] = df2['not_shifted'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1[0]))
```

The problem is the output is a dataframe which contains square brackets. To make matters worse, none of the texts within `df2['not_shifted']` are viewable/ recallable:

```
Out[421]: 
  not_shifted
0          []
1       [one]
2       [two]
3     [three]
4      [four]
5      [five]
6          []
7          []
8      [tsst]
```

Please help.

Comment: `df2.not_shifted.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) != 0 else "")` or simply `df2.not_shifted.str[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df2.not_shifted.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) != 0 else "")` or simply `df2.not_shifted.str[0]`  as solved by @Psidom

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_all(eg):
    rep = {"[":"",
       "]":"",
      "u":"",
      "}":"",
      "'":"",
        '"':"",
      "frozenset":""}
    for i,j in rep.items():
        eg = eg.replace(i,j)
    return eg

for each in df.columns:
    df[each] = df[each].apply(lambda x : replace_all(str(x)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider adding some annotation to your code to make it more useful for others. Also I wonder if it works at all with such inconsistent indentation. Best regards